# For vectors $u, v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\|v\|_\infty \leq \ 1$, prove that $u^{T}v \ \leq \ \|u\|_1$

Tags: vectors, linear-programming

I get that this is intuitive but I am struggling to get a proper proof for the same.

Comment: Hello :) What have you tried? Do you know the definitions of these norms? Then it's no big deal. Just write it explicitely, what $\|v\|_{\infty}$, $u^Tv$ and $\|u\|_1$ mean.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$u^tv=\sum_{i=1}^nu_iv_i\leq\sum_{i=1}^n|u_iv_i|=\sum_{i=1}^n|u_i||v_i|\leq\sum_{i=1}^n|u_i|\Vert v\Vert_{\infty}\leq \sum_{i=1}^n|u_i|=\Vert u\Vert_1$.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks, I will keep it in mind next time.